# Requirejs optimize tool exclude folders

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to optimize a project with r.js and am confused about how to exclude a certain folder from the copy step. My structure is...

/index.htm
/scripts/main.js
/scripts/require.js
/scripts/libs/jquery/jquery.js
/scripts/libs/other/ /* I want NONE of this folder to be moved to the build */

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your build config you can exclude files and folders using the `fileExclusionRegExp` property.

So for you example you would have:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^other$/
```

This will exclude any folders or files called **other**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) provides you with several ways of doing this:

1. for a start only the dependencies listed in main.js's `require` and their own dependencies will be included.
2. Assuming that what you have in `/other/` *is* a dependency but you still don't want them in, you can use shallow exceptions, or define them in the require.js config paths and use the `empty:` scheme.

Comment: I don't know if you're right or wrong on this, but what you say doesn't match my experience -- which is why I'm here looking at this article.  It seems that r.js automatically includes everything, even when you specify a `main.js`.  Heck, it even includes `node_modules`, if you have it, which is super-annoying.

Comment: Can confirm both node_modules and bower_components are included and being minified. Annoying indeed.