# Exclude all starting with x in requirejs module

Tags: requirejs

I am "*compiling*" some files into one requirejs module. I have a configuration like this:

```
  paths:
    lib    : "../lib"
    angular: "../lib/angular"
  modules: [
    {
      name   : 'myApp'
      exclude: ["lib/jquery", "lib/angular"]
    }
  ]
```

*(syntax is cofeescript)*

I want to **exclude all files located under `"lib"`** (e.g. starting with `lib/`) in "`myApp`" module. I now I can write them one another one like this: `["lib/jquery", "lib/angular"]` But more libs and modules will be added in the future so some kind of automatization would be nice.

Is there any way to tell require js that **"everything under `lib` should be excluded on `myApp` module"**? Somethink like this:

```
  modules: [
    {
      name   : 'myApp'
      exclude: ["lib/*"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Requirejs optimize tool exclude folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219113/requirejs-optimize-tool-exclude-folders)

Comment: @RoyDictus Question is close but not same. In regarding question, user tries to exclude a folder from whole process, I try to exclude it from one module only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a wildcard syntax, but you can define the list of excluded files as their own module, and then exclude them by name in all future modules.

Sorry, don't speak coffeescript:

```
modules: [
    {
        name: 'core',
        include: [ 'lib/jquery', 'lib/angular', 'lib/somethingelse' ]
    },
    {
        name: 'module1',
        exclude: [ 'core' ]
    },
    {
        name: 'module2',
        exclude: [ 'core' ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is the closest thing to what I try to achive.